# How do I set an Account object's type with the Partner API?

Tags: soap-api, java, wsc

I'm trying to use the partner API to upsert Account objects:

```
SObject account = new SObject();
account.setType("Account");

// set some fields
account.setField("Name", "Spacely Sprockets");

// write that bad boy
connection.upsert("Id", new SObject[] { account });
```

This works until I try to set [the account's type](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm#Tradestyle):

```
account.setField("type", "Partner");
```

Which causes the upsert to error:

> [ApiFault exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE'
>    exceptionMessage='sObject type 'Prospect' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.'
>   ]

Say what? I clearly set the `SObject`'s type to `"Account"`, not `"Partner"`. Okay – let's look at the source code for `setType(String)`:

```
public void setType(String type) {
    setField("type", type);
}
```

Well, that makes sense, in its own special way. The `setField("type", "Partner")` overwrote the type specified `setType("Account")`. But that still doesn't help me solve my original problem:

**How do I set an Account object's type with the Partner API,** using `com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject` or otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this is one of those times that Salesforce's API is actually case-sensitive: changing `"type"` to `"Type"` solves the problem.

```
account.setField("Type", "Partner");
```